# Why did Thanos need his ship to help him in the battle scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

There is a scene in the movie where

> Scarlet Witch was, what looked like, tearing Thanos apart as his armour cracked, in the final massive battle scene. Then Thanos called for his ship to fire on the ground to get him out of the situation. Did Thanos really need the help, as in was he not able to get out of it? It looked like he was dying. I didn't think Scarlet Witch was that powerful.

Comment: she is only powerful when needed, Remember how she struggled to fight that midnight female ...

Comment: @NigelFds that was because they got ambushed, neither of them were prepared, and she had to defend Vision because he was seriously injured. She comes into the Endgame battle hot off the IW Wakanda battle (from her perspective) with all that adrenaline.

Comment: @Derek still being unprepared doesnt make her under powered

Comment: @NigelFds Remember how Thanos was the most powerful being in the universe at the end of IW but because Thor surprises him he gets all but fatally injured? The element of surprise and not having time to prepare play quite an important role in a fight.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanos needed help from his ship because Scarlet Witch is more powerful than him at a range and is pretty much literally tearing him a new one. Remember in *Avengers: Infinity War* when she pretty much held her own against him even though he had 5 of the Infinity Stones in the Infinity Gauntlet and she was also trying to destroy the Mind Stone at the same time?

Scarlet Witch's powers come from the Mind Stone from the Scepeter from Struker's experiments and so that is why she is so powerful. Remember how Captain Marvel got her powers and how powerful she is?

Comment: So basically Scarlet Witch could of defeated Thanos by herself in that scene if nothing interfered

Comment: @Huangism Potentially, we will never know.

Comment: @Huangism ofc MCU != the comic books.... but in the comic books, she can definitely defeat Thanos

Comment: @Huangism Scarlet Witch is right up there on the power scale, definitely. Maybe she'd be strong enough to stop Thanos the first time if she didn't have to focus on destroying the Mind Stone; in hindsight, it might have been a better choice to just fully focus on Thanos, potentially stalling him long enough for Thor to join the fight. But of course, she couldn't have known; and in the end, the power of the characters seems to vary quite wildly depending on the circumstances (or, if you're less generous, the needs of the plot :)).

Comment: She only had a fraction of the mind stones power, Thanos had the full power of the other five. It would have been useless.

Answer (score 10):

She is indeed that powerful. She got her power from the Mind Stone. Thanos is not in the possession of any of the Infinity Stones at the moment so he is very much vulnerable to them.

Comment: Note also that Thanos, without the Gauntlet or some other weapon, has no ranged abilities. If he can't get into melee range of a sufficiently powerful opponent, he's at a serious disadvantage. And there's the factor that in the comics, Scarlet Witch has traditionally been somewhat like the Hulk: when she gets upset, very, very bad things happen to people she's upset with.